# Apply Ngx admin background image

Tags: node.js, angular

I need to apply background image for ngx-admin

http://akveo.com/ngx-admin/#/pages/dashboard

similar to http://akveo.com/blur-admin/#/tables/basic.

Gopi

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 body.nb-theme-cosmic::before {
    position: relative !important;
    background: url(http://akveo.com/blur-admin/assets/img/blur-bg.jpg) center center no-repeat !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
 }
```

Comment: i tried. No its working. Anyway thanks for the info . Any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your `@theme/styles/stlyes.scss`

```
.nb-theme-corporate nb-layout-header.fixed ~ .layout-container{
  background:url(your-url);
}
```